# Stuck getting raw_input prompt from previous while loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to make my own version of the little game in [Learn Python the Hard Way exercise 35](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex35.html), and after prompting the user to enter where they want to go first in the start() function, the program continues to give the user the prompt from start() in the candyKingdom() function. What's going on here?

Here's my code:

```
from sys import exit


def start():
    print "Welcome to Ooo! Many mathematical adventures await thee, saucy warrior!"

    global warrior
    warrior = raw_input("Why don't you tell us your name first? ")

    print "Why hello there, " + warrior + "!"

    print "Where would you like to go, " + warrior + "? \n You can type: Candy Kingdom, Ice Kingdom, Fire Kingdom, \n Treehouse, or Nightosphere"

    while True: ## This allows the user to try again if they don't type the names in just right.

        choice = raw_input("Choose wisely, " + warrior + "!: ")


        if choice == "Candy Kingdom":
            candyKingdom()

        elif choice == "Ice Kingdom":
            iceKingdom()

        elif choice == "Fire Kingdom":
            fireKingdom()

        elif choice == "Treehouse":
            treehouse()

        elif choice == "Nightosphere":
            nightosphere()

        elif choice == "exit":
            exit(0)

        else:
            print "That's not a choice! Try again!"


def candyKingdom():

    print "Thank you for coming to our rescue, " + warrior + "! We've got a major problem here!"
    print "Starchy's locked himself in the closet and he won't come out!"
    choice = raw_input("Can you help us? Yes or no? ")
```

Here I would at least expect the program to give me the prompt in candyKingdom() before crashing or whatever, but I get the prompt from the previous function again:

```
Where would you like to go, Finn? 
 You can type: Candy Kingdom, Ice Kingdom, Fire Kingdom, 
 Treehouse, or Nightosphere
Choose wisely, Finn!: Candy Kingdom
Welcome to the Candy Kingdom, Finn! We've got a major problem here!
Starchy's locked himself in the closet and he says he won't come out! Can you help us?
Choose wisely, Finn!:
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: You never break out of the while loop. Add `break` after the the call to `candyKingdom()` (and after the calls to all the other location functions)

Comment: The output you give doesn't say "Yes or No" after "Can you help us" .  Are you sure that you're running the most recent version of your code?

Comment: I added `break` both before and after the call to `candyKingdom()` and I get the same result.

Comment: @nicecore exactly the same?  Are you sure you've saved the working version of your code and that's the version you're running?

Comment: I'm an idiot - I thought I had moved the script file to my desktop but Sublime seems to have been working on the file in the original location. However, now adding "break" and taking away the `choice = raw_input` in `candyKingdom()` makes the program stop without printing the other stuff in `candyKingdom()`, what's that about?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out - `break` was before the call to `candyKingdom()` so that killed everything. Still not 100% sure why that is the way it is but I can accept it, hah. Thank you!